no internet problem when emulating ionic app on Chrome
i am new to ionic (angular) and I am building a simple app. I am so far only using my browser (chrome) to test the app. When I have the developer panel open, and I navigate, refresh, etc, I get a "No Internet" issue. I am not sure exactly what triggers it, but this happens quite often, especially if I am toggling the device, and I am using a mobile screen size.
Has anyone encountered this?

This has been happening to me recently as well - no idea why. Closing Chrome and restarting seems to fix it, though.
